# Encoding categorical columns - Label encoding vs one hot encoding for Decision trees

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree, one-hot-encoding, label-encoding

The way decision trees and random forest work using splitting logic, I was under the impression that label encoding would not be a problem for these models, as we are anyway going to split the column. For eg: if we have gender as 'male', 'female' and 'other', with label encoding, it becomes 0,1,2 which is interpreted as 0<1<2. But since we are going  to split the columns, I thought it didn't matter as it is the same thing whether we are going to split on 'male' or '0'. But when I tried both label and one hot encoding on the dataset, one hot encoding gave better accuracy and precision. 
Can you kindly share your thoughts.

```
The ACCURACY SCORE of various models on train and test are:

The accuracy score of simple decision tree on label encoded data :    TRAIN: 86.46%     TEST: 79.42%
The accuracy score of tuned decision tree on label encoded data :     TRAIN: 81.74%     TEST: 81.33%
The accuracy score of random forest ensembler on label encoded data:  TRAIN: 82.26%     TEST: 81.63%
The accuracy score of simple decision tree on one hot encoded data :  TRAIN: 86.46%     TEST: 79.74%
The accuracy score of tuned decision tree on one hot encoded data :   TRAIN: 82.04%     TEST: 81.46%
The accuracy score of random forest ensembler on one hot encoded data:TRAIN: 82.41%     TEST: 81.66%

he PRECISION SCORE of various models on train and test are:

The precision score of simple decision tree on label encoded data :             TRAIN: 78.26%   TEST: 57.92%
The precision score of tuned decision tree on label encoded data :              hTRAIN: 66.54%  TEST: 64.6%
The precision score of random forest ensembler on label encoded data:           TRAIN: 70.1%    TEST: 67.44%
The precision score of simple decision tree on one hot encoded data :           TRAIN: 78.26%   TEST: 58.84%
The precision score of tuned decision tree on one hot encoded data :            TRAIN: 68.06%   TEST: 65.81%
The precision score of random forest ensembler on one hot encoded data:         TRAIN: 70.34%   TEST: 67.32%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it as a regularization effect: your model is simpler, and so more generalizable. So you get better performances.

Taking your example of the sex feature: [male, female, other] with label encoding become [0, 1, 2].

Now suppose there is a particular configuration of the other features which works only for females: the tree needs two branches to select females, one which select sex bigger than zero, and the other which select sex lower than 2.

Instead, with one-hot encoding, you only need a branch to do the selection, say sex_female bigger than zero.